# Will ARC deallocate memory which has been allocated in ViewdidLoad Method?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

When I convert non-arc project to ARC enabled Project through Refactor in Edit ,The release methods which were in dealloc method was removed and retain keyword was changed as strong.but I have allocated in viewdidload method for synthesized strong variable.

Will it be deallocated automatically?

Comment: Depends on what it references. If it references something that has a strong reference back, you may be in trouble.

Answer (score 0):

When you are removing that view set `thatObject = nil;`

It will release it automatically.

Hope it helps..

Comment: when I come back through popviewcontroller , viewdidload will be called again? how can i allocate again If i use them in that view again?

Comment: Its quite simple, when you dont need that class, set its values to nil.

Comment: you did not understand.If set nil to that object in viewdidunload,after that when I go to another VC and come from popviewcontroller to previous controller inwhich I have set nill to that object.that object will be valid one, because I have set nill and allocated memory in viewdidload?

Comment: I mean to say when you dont need that view controller anywhere, then you set to nil.